# I know a card has been added to the hand and removed from the deck, but I can't figure out how to print the contents of that card

Tags: python, object, nonetype

```
import pygame
import random

class Deck:
    def build( self ):
        self.deck = []
        face = [ 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A' ]
        for value in range( 2, 15 ):
            for suit in [ 'C', 'D', 'H', 'S' ]:
                if value > 10:
                    new_value = face[ value - 11 ]
                    card_image = str( new_value ) + suit + '_med.jpg'
                else:
                    card_image = str( value ) + suit + '_med.jpg'
                card = Card( value, suit, card_image )
                self.deck.append( card )
    def show( self ):
        for card in self.deck:
            card.show()
    def remove_card( self ):
        card_removed = self.deck.pop()
        print( 'card removed -> {}'.format( card_removed ) )
        return card_removed
        #return self.deck.pop()

class Card:
    def __init__( self, value, suit, image_name ):
        self.value = value
        self.suit = suit
        self.image_name = image_name
    def show( self ):
        print( 'card image -> {}, suit -> {}, value -> {}'.format( self.image_name, self.suit, self.value ) )

class Hand:
    def __init__( self, name ):
        self.name = name
        self.cards = []
    def speak( self ):
        print( 'hello my name is {}'.format( self.name ) )
    def draw( self, deck ):
        card = deck.remove_card()
        self.cards.append( card )
        print( 'card drawn -> {}'.format( card ) )
        # self.cards.append( deck.remove_card() )
    def show( self ):
        for i in self.cards:
            print( i )
            
deck = Deck()
deck.build()
deck.show()

hand = Hand( 'Kristy' )
hand.speak()
hand.draw( deck )

# show updated hand and deck
hand.show()
deck.show()
```

When I run this I get None for the card object (that has been removed from the deck, and placed into the hand).  Why is this happening?  I've tried searching on "Python None object", but I'm clueless. My goal is to create a gui-based card game, but I realize that there is no point in bringing in graphics until I can the output that will be needed to put those cards on the canvas.

EDIT: I am also getting the memory addresses of the objects rather than details about the objects.

When I run the edited code (changing last line in Hand.show() to "i.show()" ), I am getting the following:

---

```
hello my name is Kristy
card removed -> <__main__.Card object at 0x0000015F48C1F6D0>
card drawn -> <__main__.Card object at 0x0000015F48C1F6D0>
```

Comment: When you say that you get `None`, what exact command gives you `None`? `Hand.draw` does not return anything, but it seems to update the hand correctly.

Comment: Please add error output you are getting to your question here.  People like to be able to reproduce your problem to better assist.

Comment: I have added in the output.

Comment: I do not know what I have done to get rid of the None issue, but what remains is the above output for the "card removed" and "card drawn" results.

Comment: That is the normal print format for an object.  If you want to be able to print an object using print, you define the `__str__` for the object.  Answer below.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is the normal string representation for a class.  If you want to get a "human-readable" version, define the `__str__` function.  Here is what the new Card class would look like:

```
class Card:
    def __init__( self, value, suit, image_name ):
        self.value = value
        self.suit = suit
        self.image_name = image_name
    
    def show( self ):  
        print(self)

    def __str__(self):
        return ( 'card image -> {}, suit -> {}, value -> {}'.format( self.image_name, self.suit, self.value ) )
```

Then you can say `print (card);` and get the output formerly done by `Card.show()`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  After implementing that change, I get the above shown in my edited initial comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pygame
import random

class Deck:
    def __init__( self ):
        self.deck = []
        self.build()

    def build( self ):
        face = [ 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A' ]
        for value in range( 2, 15 ):
            for suit in [ 'C', 'D', 'H', 'S' ]:
                if value > 10:
                    new_value = face[ value - 11 ]
                    card_image = str( new_value ) + suit + '_med.jpg'
                else:
                    card_image = str( value ) + suit + '_med.jpg'
                card = Card( value, suit, card_image )
                self.deck.append( card )
    
    def show( self ):
        for card in self.deck:
            card.show()
    
    def remove_card( self ):
        card_removed = self.deck.pop()
        print( 'card removed -> {} of {}'.format( card_removed.value, card_removed.suit ) )
        return card_removed

class Card:
    def __init__( self, value, suit, image_name ):
        self.value = value
        self.suit = suit
        self.image_name = image_name
    
    def show( self ):
        print( 'card image -> {}, suit -> {}, value -> {}'.format( self.image_name, self.suit, self.value ) )
    
class Hand:
    def __init__( self, name ):
        self.name = name
        self.cards = []
        self.speak()
    
    def speak( self ):
        print( 'hello my name is {}'.format( self.name ) )
    
    def draw( self, deck ):
        self.cards.append( deck.remove_card() )
    
    def show( self ):
        for i in self.cards:
            print( 'card in hand -> {} of {}'.format( i.value, i.suit ) )
   
            
deck = Deck()
deck.show()

hand = Hand( 'Kristy' )
hand.draw( deck )
hand.draw( deck )
hand.show()
deck.show()
```

---

Here is the output:

```
hello my name is Kristy
card removed -> 14 of S
card removed -> 14 of H
card in hand -> 14 of S
card in hand -> 14 of H
card image -> 2C_med.jpg, suit -> C, value -> 2
card image -> 2D_med.jpg, suit -> D, value -> 2
card image -> 2H_med.jpg, suit -> H, value -> 2
card image -> 2S_med.jpg, suit -> S, value -> 2
card image -> 3C_med.jpg, suit -> C, value -> 3
card image -> 3D_med.jpg, suit -> D, value -> 3
card image -> 3H_med.jpg, suit -> H, value -> 3
card image -> 3S_med.jpg, suit -> S, value -> 3
card image -> 4C_med.jpg, suit -> C, value -> 4
card image -> 4D_med.jpg, suit -> D, value -> 4
card image -> 4H_med.jpg, suit -> H, value -> 4
card image -> 4S_med.jpg, suit -> S, value -> 4
card image -> 5C_med.jpg, suit -> C, value -> 5
card image -> 5D_med.jpg, suit -> D, value -> 5
card image -> 5H_med.jpg, suit -> H, value -> 5
card image -> 5S_med.jpg, suit -> S, value -> 5
card image -> 6C_med.jpg, suit -> C, value -> 6
card image -> 6D_med.jpg, suit -> D, value -> 6
card image -> 6H_med.jpg, suit -> H, value -> 6
card image -> 6S_med.jpg, suit -> S, value -> 6
card image -> 7C_med.jpg, suit -> C, value -> 7
card image -> 7D_med.jpg, suit -> D, value -> 7
card image -> 7H_med.jpg, suit -> H, value -> 7
card image -> 7S_med.jpg, suit -> S, value -> 7
card image -> 8C_med.jpg, suit -> C, value -> 8
card image -> 8D_med.jpg, suit -> D, value -> 8
card image -> 8H_med.jpg, suit -> H, value -> 8
card image -> 8S_med.jpg, suit -> S, value -> 8
card image -> 9C_med.jpg, suit -> C, value -> 9
card image -> 9D_med.jpg, suit -> D, value -> 9
card image -> 9H_med.jpg, suit -> H, value -> 9
card image -> 9S_med.jpg, suit -> S, value -> 9
card image -> 10C_med.jpg, suit -> C, value -> 10
card image -> 10D_med.jpg, suit -> D, value -> 10
card image -> 10H_med.jpg, suit -> H, value -> 10
card image -> 10S_med.jpg, suit -> S, value -> 10
card image -> JC_med.jpg, suit -> C, value -> 11
card image -> JD_med.jpg, suit -> D, value -> 11
card image -> JH_med.jpg, suit -> H, value -> 11
card image -> JS_med.jpg, suit -> S, value -> 11
card image -> QC_med.jpg, suit -> C, value -> 12
card image -> QD_med.jpg, suit -> D, value -> 12
card image -> QH_med.jpg, suit -> H, value -> 12
card image -> QS_med.jpg, suit -> S, value -> 12
card image -> KC_med.jpg, suit -> C, value -> 13
card image -> KD_med.jpg, suit -> D, value -> 13
card image -> KH_med.jpg, suit -> H, value -> 13
card image -> KS_med.jpg, suit -> S, value -> 13
card image -> AC_med.jpg, suit -> C, value -> 14
card image -> AD_med.jpg, suit -> D, value -> 14
```

Hi friends,  the solution is to use "self" from within the class of the object being operated on, and the "object name" when operating on the object from outside of its class.  Thanks for the taking the time to try and offer suggestions.  Cheers!